# Unicode String Interpolation

Tags: string, swift, unicode

I'm getting an the following string from my server `"\u{EEEE}`. After parsing the value the backlash is escaped and the string becomes `"\\u{EEEE}"`. How do I convert the string back to the icon  ?

I tried to just send `EEEE` from the server but I haven't been able to interpolate the value into a `\u{}` tag.

Comment: I tried poking around the internet and couldn't really find anything. You *could* parse the hex value out, and use that to make a `UnicodeScalar`, but I can't think of any nicer ways.

Comment: What's the function you use for escaping the character and why do you do it?

Comment: I'm not using any function to escape characters. It is probably transformed by `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData`

Comment: @AMomchilov your suggestion actually worked. `String(UnicodeScalar(Int(iconHex, radix: 16)!))`

Comment: Lol that's pretty gross but I guess it works xD

Comment: @vacawama this is not a duplicate. I have an answer that explains the escaping problem and i wanted to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried poking around the internet and couldn't really find anything. You could parse the hex value out, and use that to make a UnicodeScalar, but I can't think of any nicer ways.